# How do I insert object created with document.createElement into template?

Tags: vuejs2

I like to know how I can insert a Element that has already been created with the document.createElement method into the template. I am not sure how to proceed here because eventually I would also like to bind the contents of that particular textBox. Here is the (non working) code that I have up till now to illustrate what I like to do:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p id="status">{{ statusMessage }}</p>
    <div id="output" v-html="textBox"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Result',
  data() {
    return {
      statusMessage: "Status",
      textBox: Object,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.textBox = this.$someModule.createTextBox()
    console.log('textBox should become: '+this.textBox)
       // Shows: textbox should become: [object HTMLTextAreaElement]
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **v-html** is a directive that allow you to use raw html text.

> ref: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

Second of all, you can you a **ref** directive to create a link to you element (ref="someName"):

```
<div id="output" ref="textBox"></div>
```

Then:

```
const el = this.$refs.textBox;
el.appendChild('entity which you want to append');
```