# How to update html styles with component methods in Nuxt app

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am trying to edit `document.html.style` from a Nuxt.js component. I've tried wrapping my code inside of an if statement to check for the browser versus the server as detailed here, but consistently get the error `document.html is undefined` when I try and build the app.

I'm generating a random color for the background and saving it to the component state at `bgColor`. I can bind that to a div within my component, but want to also bind it to the html `background-color` css style.

```
    methods: {
        newMethod() {
            if (process.browser) {
                // hex color value saved in component state
                document.html.style.backgroundColor = this.bgColor
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to bind the color saved in my component state to the `html` document's `background-color` css style.

Comment: try to do that via ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54353241/how-do-i-insert-object-created-with-document-createelement-into-template/54353409#54353409

Comment: I tried that however I don't have access to the base html template with Nuxt.. so I cannot add a ref to that template.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a solution that worked for me - I simply had to create a store and use the mutations to target `document.body.style.backgroundColor` and I no longer got the error.